# Separating mutable borrows for trait with lifetime parameter

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I ran into an issue while trying to define and use a trait with methods that borrow `self` mutably.

Some context that might make it easier: I am working on a toy compiler, and the problem I was trying to solve was to define a trait for code nodes, which are either statements or expressions. The trait was meant to be used for traversing code mutably (for rewriting purposes). The abstraction I was trying to create was a "code node" that may have any number of children that are either statements or expressions. This is how it went:

```rust
// Actually these are enums with different payload types for different kinds of exprs/stmts,
// but this is not relevant.
struct Expression;
struct Statement;

trait CodeNode<'a>
where
    Self::ExprIter: Iterator<Item = &'a mut Expression>,
    Self::StmtIter: Iterator<Item = &'a mut Statement>,
{
    type ExprIter;
    type StmtIter;

    fn child_exprs(&'a mut self) -> Self::ExprIter;
    fn child_stmts(&'a mut self) -> Self::StmtIter;
}
```

This trait would be then implemented for quite a few types (I have a separate type for different kinds of statements and expressions).

The way I tried to use it was:

```rust
fn process<'a>(node: &'a mut impl CodeNode<'a>) {
    for _stmt in node.child_stmts() {
        // ...
    }

    for _expr in node.child_exprs() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And this is where the problem lies. Rust compiler treats a call to `node.child_stmts` as a mutable borrow of `node` for the *entire* lifetime `'a`, and so it does not allow a call to `node.child_exprs` later in the same function. Here is how the error looks:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*node` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:21:18
   |
16 | fn process<'a>(node: &'a mut impl CodeNode<'a>) {
   |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
17 |     for _stmt in node.child_stmts() {
   |                  ------------------
   |                  |
   |                  first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                  argument requires that `*node` is borrowed for `'a`
...
21 |     for _expr in node.child_exprs() {
   |                  ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

What I want to do is to somehow make compiler aware of the fact that `node` implements `CodeNode<'a>` for *any* lifetime parameter, and so it should use two separate lifetimes for two
calls, but I can't quite figure out a way to do it.

Any suggestions are welcome, I don't have a lot of experience with Rust, so maybe I am missing some more high-level solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lifetime `'a` is constrained by the `CodeNode` so both functions will be called with the same lifetime, but what you want are two lifetimes constrained by the two functions. So why not do something like this.

```rust
struct Expression;
struct Statement;

trait CodeNode
{
    type ExprIter<'a> : Iterator<Item = &'a mut Expression>; //unstable
    type StmtIter<'a> : Iterator<Item = &'a mut Statement>; //unstable

    fn child_exprs<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Self::ExprIter<'a>;
    fn child_stmts<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Self::StmtIter<'a>;
}

fn process(node: &mut impl CodeNode) {
    for _stmt in node.child_stmts() {
        // ...
    }

    for _expr in node.child_exprs() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I had to use the unstable feature of [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md), but I believe this is what you want.
I also want to express that iterating over mutable references might not be a good idea and maybe you should change your program structure if that is possible.

EDIT:

@pretzelhammer proposed in the comments the following link which might be interesting: [Solving the generalized streaming iterator problem without gats](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2018/08/03/solving-the-generalized-streaming-iterator-problem-without-gats.html)

Comment: To add more context to this answers readers my also want to read the [Generic Associated Types RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) and [Solving the Generalized Streaming Iterator Problem without GATs](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2018/08/03/solving-the-generalized-streaming-iterator-problem-without-gats.html).

Comment: This looks pretty good, but I am trying to stick to stable for now. In the article @pretzelhammer linked, a solution with HRTBs is described which actually works for my use case, since no trait implementations restrict the lifetime parameter.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but for people who can't use nightly for some reason, HRTBs (`for<'a> T: CodeNode<'a>`) might be the way to go.